# Confusion on what a Faithful Functor is

Tags: category-theory

This is my first experience with Cat Theory, and I saw an example that mentioned a functor is "faithful." So, I googled it--and I got that it's a functor that's injective on homsets.

And, a homset is just a set of functions between two objects in the domain. Does this mean, if I have a Functor $F: C\to D$, and objects $a,b\in obj(C)$, then $$F(homset(a,b)) = homset(Fa, Fb)$$
s.t. for morphisms $f,g\in homset(a,b)$, we get that $Ff = Fg$ iff $f=g$?

If so, why isn't the functor $F$ just injective, or is it because it's only injective on morphisms? Like, we could still have $Fa = Fb$ and $a\neq b$ where $a, b\in obj(C)$?

So, does it just mean that $F$ is injective on morphisms rather than objects too?

Comment: yes only on morphisms

Comment: Keep in mind that you almost never want to compare two objects to see if they’re equal. “Injective on objects” would mean that $FX = FY$ implies $X = Y$. A better suggestion would be “any isomorphism $FX \to FY$ arises as $Ff$ for a unique $f : X \to Y$”.

Comment: "a homset is just a set of functions between two objects in the domain" - that isn't always true. A homset is a set of *arrows* between two objects, and an arrow might or might not be a function, depending on what category you're considering.

Answer (score 3):

In  fact it is not required that $F$ is injective on objects. It means that for any two objects $a, b$ of $C$ the function

$$F : homset(a,b) \to homset(Fa,Fb)$$

is injective. Note that it is not required that this function is surjective, thus you must not write $F(homset(a,b)) = homset(Fa,Fb)$. In general we only  have the obvious inclusion $F(homset(a,b)) \subset homset(Fa,Fb)$.

Example: Let $Grp$ denote the category of groups and group homomorphisms and $Set$ the category of sets and functions of sets. Define
$$F : Grp \to Set$$
as the functor forgetting the group structure. This is faithful because two distinct homomorphisms $f, g : a \to b$ are also distinct when viewed as functions $Ff, Fg : Fa \to Fb$. But $F$ is not injective on objects: For each set $s$ with more than one element there exist more than one group $a$ such that $Fa = s$.